# How to combine ActiveRecord Relations? Merge not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Initially when I was trying to build a histogram of all `Items` that have an `Order` start between a given set of dates based on exactly what the item was (`:name_id`) and the frequency of that `:name_id`, I was using the following code:

```
dates = ["May 27, 2016", "May 30, 2016"]
items = Item.joins(:order).where("orders.start >= ?", dates.first).where("orders.start <= ?", dates.last)
histogram = {}
items.pluck(:name_id).uniq.each do |name_id|
  histogram[name_id] = items.where(name_id:name_id).count
end
```

This code worked FINE.

Now, however, I'm trying to build a histogram that's more expansive. I still want to capture frequency of `:name_id` over a period of time, but now I want to bound that time by `Order` start and end. I'm having trouble however, combining the ActiveRecord Relations that follow the queries. Specifically, if my queries are as follows:

```
items_a = Item.joins(:order).where("orders.start >= ?", dates.first).where("orders.start <= ?", dates.last)
items_b = Item.joins(:order).where("orders.end >= ?", dates.first).where("orders.end <= ?", dates.last)
```

**How do I join the 2 queries so that my code below that acts on query objects still works?**

```
items.pluck(:name_id).each do |name_id|
  histogram[name_id] = items.where(name_id:name_id).count
end
```

What I've tried:

`+`, but of course that doesn't work because it turns the result into an Array where methods like `pluck` don't work:

```
(items_a + items_b).pluck(:name_id)
=> error
```

`merge`, this is what all the SO answers seem to say... but it doesn't work for me because, as the docs say, `merge` figures out the intersection, so my result is like this:

```
items_a.count
=> 100
items_b.count
=> 30
items_a.merge(items_b)
=> 15
```

FYI currently, I've monkey-patched this with the below, but it's not very ideal. Thanks for the help!

```
name_ids = (items_a.pluck(:name_id) + items_b.pluck(:name_id)).uniq
name_ids.each do |name_id|
  # from each query object, return the ids of the item objects that meet the name_id criterion
  item_object_ids = items_a.where(name_id:name_id).pluck(:id) + items_b.where(name_id:name_id).pluck(:id) + items_c.where(name_id:name_id).pluck(:id)
  # then check the item objects for duplicates and then count up. btw I realize that with the uniq here I'm SOMEWHAT doing an intersection of the objects, but it's nowhere near as severe... the above example where merge yielded a count of 15 is not that off from the truth, when the count should be maybe -5 from the addition of the 2 queries
  histogram[name_id] = item_object_ids.uniq.count
end
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? The newest (prerelease) versions do support `items_a.or(items_b)`.

Comment: A quick fix would be to describe the whole condition using SQL: `Item.joins(:order).where("(orders.start BETWEEN :min AND :max) OR (orders.end BETWEEN :min AND :max)", min: dates.first, max: dates.last)`

Comment: As an alternative, the gem `squeel` adds some SQL algebra goodness to ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your two queries into one:

```
items = Item.joins(:order).where(
  "(orders.start >= ? AND orders.start <= ?) OR (orders.end >= ? AND orders.end <= ?)", 
  dates.first, dates.last, dates.first, dates.last
```

)

This might be a little more readable:

```
items = Item.joins(:order).where(
  "(orders.start >= :first AND orders.start <= :last) OR (orders.end >= :first AND orders.end <= :last)", 
  { first: dates.first, last: dates.last }
)
```

Rails 5 will support an `or` method that might make this a little nicer:

```
items_a = Item.joins(:order).where(
  "orders.start >= :first AND orders.start <= :last", 
  { first: dates.first, last: dates.last }
).or(
  "orders.end >= :first AND orders.end <= :last", 
  { first: dates.first, last: dates.last }
)
```

Or maybe not any nicer in this case

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be a bit cleaner:

```
date_range = "May 27, 2016".to_date.."May 30, 2016".to_date

items = Item.joins(:order).where('orders.start' => date_range).or('orders.end' => date_range)
```